# JAVA - How to generate Random number between 2 integers?

Tags: java, random, input, console, integer

i'm trying to read in two integer numbers from the console and then display a random integer number generated between these two numbers.

this is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Question8{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int first, second;

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter first integer: ");
        int numOne;
        numOne = myScanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You have keyed in " + numOne);

        System.out.println("Enter second integer: ");
        int numTwo;
        numTwo = myScanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You have keyed in " + numTwo);

        Random generator = new Random();
        //int num = generator.nextInt(numOne) + numTwo;
        System.out.println("Random number: " + numOne + generator.nextInt(numTwo - numOne));
    }
}
```

after i execute this program..
i do not get the random number that's between the 2 integers.

this is my output:

```
Enter first integer: 
20
You have keyed in 20
Enter second integer: 
30
You have keyed in 30
Random number: 204
```

hope you guys can help me in any way you can (:

Comment: random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min

Comment: Actually you get a number between 0 and 10. But you try to add the `numOne` in a wrong way. It is just being concatenated to the result string. So you see `20` and `4` but you would like `24` I guess. So you should do that addition of the numbers within parentheses.

Comment: @maba i'm not trying to do addition. i'm trying to read in two integers. and then generate the random integer between those 2 integers from input/console. like.. if i type in 20 and 30.. i should get a random number between 20 and 30..

Comment: Check your last line: `System.out.println("Random number: " + numOne + generator.nextInt(numTwo - numOne));`. Change that to `System.out.println("Random number: " + (numOne + generator.nextInt(numTwo - numOne)));` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `first` is always the smaller value and use `new Random().nextInt(second - first) + first;`. `first` is in the range of possible generated numbers, `second` is exclusive.

Comment: i got error - error: `incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Random`. i edited this part - `Random generator = new Random().nextInt(numTwo - numOne)+numOne;`
     `System.out.println("Random number: " + generator);`

Comment: the error is pointed to `Random generator = new Random().nextInt(numTwo - numOne)+numOne;`

Comment: that was just supposed to be a demonstration how to generate random numbers matching your criteria, not a solution you can simply copy paste. sry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

A random generator (Method in java.lang.Math?) will generate a random double x, where 0 <= x <= 1. Just multiply x with the range and add any offset to the product.